# how to properly add a custom field within the product entity

Tags: symfony, shopware

I need to customize a product by adding a text input field onto on the admin. In order to do that I firstly read the [this](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/administration/add-custom-field) doc which actually did what I was expecting, added an input when in the screen you are suppose to register a product, in this case it added the an input with the manufactureId as value.

like this: [image]

Now the next step that I'm not being able to figure it out is to change that value. So, instead of the manufacturerId I would like to have a customString value there. This should be done via plugin.

I also follow other guides in order to add, migration, a product subscriber and a custom extension to the product entity, as far as I know they are working as the table was created at the database and I could dump the request at the ProductSubscriber class.

My code are the ones within the I already cited an this [one](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/add-complex-data-to-existing-entities)

Comment: I am not 100% sure what exactly you want to do here?
You have already added a custom field set incuding your custom fields?
When do you want to change the value of which field?
By code on which event or by the user it self?

Comment: The documentation doesn't tell me how(or at least I was not able to find it) I may bind to the product other value than the manufacturer ID. That's what I meant when I said "change the value". So I would like to be able to add custom values other than what already exists on product.